# Zend2 - get cookie from remote server with CURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to get cookies content from remote server using Zend2 Client, my code:

```
$client = new \Zend\Http\Client;
$client->setHeaders($options);
$adapter = new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();
$client->setAdapter($adapter);  
$client->setUri($url);
$result = $client->getResponse();
$headers = $result->getHeaders();
$cookie = $headers->get('Cookie');
var_dump($cookie);
```

Where $url is for example http://example.com and $options looks like:

```
array('useragent' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
```

But var_dump($cookie) returns boolean(false) when I'm sure there is a cookie (checked with firebug). Why so? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, its `Set-Cookie` when the server returns you cookie through response header. Currently you are using `Cookie` which is available with request header when you send cookie to a Server.

```
$cookie = $headers->get('Set-Cookie');
```

Another thing, are you sure `example.com` returns you cookie?? Alternately you can try with other sites like `www.youtube.com` that returns cookie.

Comment: Well, still nothing - boolean(false), even when I've changed url to http://youtube.com. Well, as I said example.com was only a example.

Comment: I missed the part `for example`. Please try `var_dump` on `$result->getHeaders()` and check what it has.

Comment: I've passed to zend client options 'curloptions' => array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
            ), and i get: string(1204) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:05:22 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8 Connection: close Vary: Accept-Encoding Expires: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:05:22 GMT Cache-Control: max-age=0 Content-Encoding: gzip UÍnă6>ŰO1ĺ%ľčüô/+šČ&ŮmIclíĹ ¤ąDľ$eEZě%@bÇČ­č-ń{˛,Gm°h+ÉořÍĚGĘýćäňxňëř~\ĂřúÍůŮ1Ľ7űÇLNĂ3ÜĽôô$6&;¤´...") and so on. How to decode it?